# Manage memory with setImageWithURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uiimageview

I have a bunches of cell that contain UIImageView in UICollectionView and i've using setImageWithURL to load image in each cell, but if it load too much (i.e 100 cell) my app become crashing. Its definitely because of memory issues, i know this is not rare case in Mobile platform, but i still need help from experient guys.

I think it come from setImageWithURL (AFNetworking) problem, it still keep the catch from previous image link and bytheway i've using infinity scrolled, so the system will hold all the images, and memory can not stand. I need a solution for clear the cath images file or some thing to manage the memory. Any help ?

Comment: Show us code and errors please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AFNetworking + Many imageviews = Crash -> Received memory warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514038/afnetworking-many-imageviews-crash-received-memory-warning)

Comment: Are you reusing the cells?

Comment: setImageWithURL of AFNetworking still keep the catch file even i don't use it anymore. Its the problem